# Does kivy have the capability to create a scrollable grid of menus with text and icons, as in the image below, if yes, how?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a dictionary, like the one in the image, where I can translate English to my native language. I have achieved the navigation drawer, but the challenge is how to create a scrollable home screen menu, as in the image. Pls, any idea how I can go about it?[image: This is a screenshot of the homepage of an android app that I took]

Comment: Try using a `GridLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks